# Plot an hourly time series in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

I have a `df`, data for `7 days`, bucketed by **hour**. So my index is `time`, and my columns are `open`, `Time` and `hour`.

I would like to plot the **average** of all the data points at any particular hour, i.e.

-x axis is 0 to 24, and

-y axis is average of "open" for that hour.

I could use `for loops` but I want to know if there is a more Pythonic way to achieve this

Below is my dataframe:

```
     time               open       Time         hour
2018-09-12 03:00:00    0.046 2018-09-12 03:00:00 3 

2018-09-12 04:00:00    0.042 2018-09-12 04:00:00 4 

2018-09-12 05:00:00    0.039 2018-09-12 05:00:00 5 

2018-09-12 06:00:00    0.039 2018-09-12 06:00:00 6 

2018-09-12 07:00:00    0.032 2018-09-12 07:00:00 7 

2018-09-12 08:00:00    0.032 2018-09-12 08:00:00 8 

2018-09-12 09:00:00    0.030 2018-09-12 09:00:00 9 

2018-09-12 10:00:00    0.030 2018-09-12 10:00:00 10 

2018-09-12 11:00:00    0.042 2018-09-12 11:00:00 11
```

Comment: Why do you have two identical `Time`  columns

Comment: `df.groupby('hour')['open'].mean().plot.bar()`?